# What does this for loop do? - Sheet Music

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Below is the full code which takes the written characters from the dictionary and turns it into sheet music. I was wondering if anyone could explain to me how the for loop works.

```
char2notes = { 
  ' ':("a4 a4 ", "r2 "),
  'a':("<c a>2 ", "<e' a'>2 "),
  'b':("e2 ", "e'4 <e' g'> "),
  'c':("g2 ", "d'4 e' "), 
  'd':("e2 ", "e'4 a' "),
  'e':("<c g>2 ", "a'4 <a' c'> "),
  'f':("a2 ", "<g' a'>4 c'' "),
  'g':("a2 ", "<g' a'>4 a' "),
  'h':("r4 g ", " r4 g' "),
  'i':("<c e>2 ", "d'4 g' "),
  'j':("a4 a ", "g'4 g' "),
  'k':("a2 ", "<g' a'>4 g' "),
  'l':("e4 g ", "a'4 a' "),
  'm':("c4 e ", "a'4 g' "),
  'n':("e4 c ", "a'4 g' "),
  'o':("<c a g>2  ", "a'2 "),
  'p':("a2 ", "e'4 <e' g'> "),
  'q':("a2 ", "a'4 a' "),
  'r':("g4 e ", "a'4 a' "),
  's':("a2 ", "g'4 a' "),
  't':("g2 ", "e'4 c' "),
  'u':("<c e g>2  ", "<a' g'>2"),
  'v':("e4 e ", "a'4 c' "),
  'w':("e4 a ", "a'4 c' "),
  'x':("r4 <c d> ", "g' a' "),
  'y':("<c g>2  ", "<a' g'>2"),
  'z':("<e a>2 ", "g'4 a' "),
  '\n':("r1 r1 ", "r1 r1 "),
  ',':("r2 ", "r2"),
  '.':("<c e a>2 ", "<a c' e'>2")
}

txt = "Love one another and you will be happy. It is as simple as that."

upper_staff = ""
lower_staff = "" 
for i in txt.lower():
    (l,u) = char2notes[i]
    upper_staff += u
    lower_staff += l

staff = "{\n\\new PianoStaff << \n"
staff += "  \\new Staff {" + upper_staff + "}\n"  
staff += "  \\new Staff { \clef bass " + lower_staff + "}\n"  
staff += ">>\n}\n"

title = """\header {
  title = "Love One Another"
  composer = "Bernd Klein using Python"
  tagline = "Copyright: Bernd Klein"
}"""

print (title + staff)
```

Comment: Simple. Takes each letter from the string txt, converts it to lower case, and uses it to index the dictionary char2notes, which has a pair of chords (I assume) corresponding to each letter of the alphabet (and some punctuation too) - one for the upper and one for the lower staff.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Loop over the characters ("i") in txt.lower() - txt converted to lowercase.
for i in txt.lower():

    # Assign the values in the char2notes dictionary value corresponding to the key 
    # (the character within txt.lower()) to variables l and u.
    (l,u) = char2notes[i]

    # Append u to the upper_staff string
    upper_staff += u

    # Append l to the lower_staff string
    lower_staff += l
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are really just lists of characters, so your for loop iterates through each character in the string, finds the tuple that corresponds to that character (or that character's lowercase equivalent if it's uppercase), appends the first element in the tuple to your lower_staff string using the += operator, and does the same with the second element and the upper_staff.